# Caffeine Cache not loading from memory

Tags: caching, caffeine

We are using Caffeine for caching purpose. The setup seems to be pretty simple. We setup the cache in the following way

```
LoadingCache<Triple<Long, Long, Long>, Result> cache = Caffeine.newBuilder()
            .maximumSize(1000)
            .refreshAfterWrite(240, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .build(new CacheDataLoader());

public class CacheDataLoader implements CacheLoader<Triple<Long, Long, Long>, Result>  {
    @Override
    public Result load(@Nonnull Triple<Long, Long, Long> id) throws Exception 
    {
      -------
    }

    @Override
    public Result reload(@Nonnull Triple<Long, Long, Long> id, @Nonnull Result oldValue) throws Exception {
       ---------
    }
}
```

When we do `cache.get(id)`, it is always triggering the `load` function in `CacheDataLoader` which will load from a database. As a result the data is never being fetched from in memory. Based on the documentation, the `load` should be triggered only if the requested key is not in memory. Is that not correct? Is there anything wrong with how we are configuring the cache.

Any insight is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: This is often because the cache key lacks good equals and hashCode methods. Can you check those?

Comment: @BenManes thanks for your response. That was my hunch initially since we are using Triple so I changed it to just String and still had the same behaviour

Comment: Can you provide a test case?

Comment: The other possibilities are that the key is not generated in a repeatable manner, that weakKeys was enabled, or that the result is null (not computable). If you can provide a reproducible test that would help in identifying the problem.